# Wordpress users migration to rails devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, hash, passwords, migration

I am in middle of my wordpress migration to rails. In rails I will be using devise, the only problem is the existing wordpress users hash password.

If I migrate all users to rails how can I authenticate with there old password. Is it possible for rails to generate same hash as wordpress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You will need to [create a custom encryptor](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-custom-encryptor) for Devise.

Wordpress can hash passwords in several ways, but [by default uses phpass](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L0). There is a ruby implementation as a gem called [phpass-ruby](https://github.com/uu59/phpass-ruby), that you could use as a basis for your encryptor. You may need to modify this to use your WP salt. Alternatively, check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/stuartbates/9663498).

But...

If possible, I'd recommend importing the users, then [sending out an email to each](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Mass-password-reset-and-email-notification) asking them to create a new password. If your old passwords are MD5 hashed, this will be more secure, and arguably it could be more user-friendly, as users (or software) may not associate the old password with the new site.

Answer (score 3):

This will allow authentication with the old password. If they change their password, it will use the default Devise BCrypt hash instead.

`Gemfile`

```
gem 'phpass-ruby' # check WordPress passwords
```

`User.rb`

```
require "phpass"
class User < ApplicationRecord

  # For Devise to use WordPress passwords. WordPress uses a portable PHPass of MD5 plus a salt.
  def valid_password?(password)
    return false if encrypted_password.blank?
    begin
      return true if super
    rescue BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash => e
      logger.info "Invalid BCrypt password for #{email}. Fallback to PHPass."
    end
    # Fallback to PHPass
    phpass = Phpass.new(8)
    return phpass.check(password, encrypted_password)
  end
```

Comment: This seems to no-longer work. (perhaps the wordpress version matters?)